# How to make ubuntu auto-mount my encrypted home again?

Tags: ecryptfs

So I recently changed my password and I've been unable to log in properly since then.

I've rewrapped my ecryptfs key and used it to mount my encrypted filesystem successfully using `ecryptfs-recover-private`.

So the wrapper password and the user password are the same at this point, but Ubuntu still fails to auto-mount.

Also, `ecryptfs-mount-private` does nothing but output a message like `Inserted auth tok with sig [signiture] into user session keyring`, this token however does nothing.

I've tried reverting back to the old password, but the situation persisted.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem turned out being that I had accidentally revoked read permissions on the wrapped-passphrase file.